# How to position textviews on top of image based background when the background scales?

Tags: android, textview, imageview, location, position

Have a question regarding positioning of TextViews.

So basically I have a background image(schema) which is here https://prnt.sc/jz22p4

My goal is to position textviews on top of this background https://prnt.sc/jz22z3

Problem is that on different device sizes the background schema image scales, and then my textviews tend to go off. I tried solving this by using constraintlayout with percentage based guidelines, but no luck. I really want to avoid creating multiple layouts just for this schema.

Anyone can advice how to solve this? Or maybe someone could reference me to some source where a similar problem was solved? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a background image and margin positioning for each density(HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI, ...) => https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

You just need to create additional folders like:

- drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi... for image background
- values-hdpi, values-xhdpi(with dimen.xml files)... for dimensions

Comment: What are the main densities which I should take into account?

Comment: Here you will find more infos about wich density you have to manage. 
Look at the **Screen sizes and densities** section here =>
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/#Screens

Comment: So I just need to cover only these dimensions:

ldpi  
mdpi  
tvdpi  
hdpi  
xhdpi  
xxhdpi  
  
?

Comment: There is no more a lot of use of ldpi and mdpi in recent Android device, is more about which Android API you are targeting.

If you are targeting 5.0 and above, I will suggest you to manage only : **hdpi, xhdp, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi**

Comment: Thank you! I was totally lost and confused, now it's much more clear! Can you explain how API is connected to screen sizes?